# redirect after login and logout

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

I don't how how chang path to redirect my website after login and logout. In first example I found that I must change `RedirectIfAuthenticated`. But If I have

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->route('myroute');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

which doesn't redirect me when I want it to. And where can I change the redirect place after logout?

Comment: post your controller please.

Comment: Which controller?

Comment: Login controller

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
return redirect('your endpoint');
```

the detail implementation is depending on your controller/middleware

Comment: t doesn't work. earlier I was able to and I thought that i do it that. Itry remove every information about redirect from the function. I left only return $next($request); and it redirect me http://pasted.co/04172089 [code]

Comment: so there is a problem with the conditional `if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())` or `return redirect()->route('myroute');`

Comment: How I can solve this problem and why redirect me without redirect() into this middleware?

Comment: try to change `return redirect()->route('myroute');` to `return redirect('your endpoint');`

Comment: I tryed. But I don't understand why redirect works (but not to path what I want), if I remove any information of redirect from middleware.

Answer (score 0):

first check weather you have asign the name of the routes? you try to redirect('myroute') but in your route file have you define this route or not? let you first check if not then define it.

Comment: This route exist. I change it's name for post needs

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home'; // change it as you like
```